# OWL:Nothing dl query issue

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I have written an interface that given for example the Pizza ontology it can distinguish between asserted and inferred axioms. For example, given `Class: Food SubClassOf: Thing` it will tell you that it is inferred. My question is that if I have an unsatisfiable class TomatoTopping, and I want to know if `Class: TomatoTopping SubClassOf: Nothing` is asserted, inferred or none, I will get the response that the axiom doesn't exist. Although I can see TomatoTopping under Nothing in the hierarchy. What is the problem? Can't I query such an axiom or my logic is flawed?

This is the code that identifies `Class: Food SubClassOf: Thing` but not `Class: TomatoTopping SubClassOf: Nothing`

```java
    // parsing input
    Set<OntologyAxiomPair> frame = parsingProcess(tool, input);
    Iterator<OntologyAxiomPair> frameit = frame.iterator();

    while (frameit.hasNext()) {
        OntologyAxiomPair newPair = frameit.next();
        OWLAxiom tempAx = newPair.getAxiom();

        // the axiom type must be anything but declaration
        if (!tempAx.isOfType(AxiomType.DECLARATION)) {
            // get asseted and inferred axioms
            Set<OWLAxiom> asserted = getOntology().getAxioms();

            if (asserted.contains(tempAx)) {
                Result = "System: this axiom is an asserted axiom.";
                displayUserMessage(Result, asetBlue);
                break;
            }

            // Use an inferred axiom generators
            else 
            {
                // Calling TrOWL
                RELReasoner reasoner = relfactory.createReasoner(getOntology());
                if(reasoner.isEntailed( tempAx)){
                    Result = "System: this axiom is an inferred axiom.";
                    displayUserMessage(Result, asetMagenta);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I discovered what the problem is. The Manchester Syntax parser needs a datafactory.

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager = inputOntology.getOWLOntologyManager();
    this.dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
```

Since the manager is not classified by a reasoner, the OWL:Nothing does not appear. Do you know of a way to classify a manager and then extract datafactroy?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about what you've already done.  That is, please show some code;  there's not enough to diagnose your problem yet.

Comment: I added my code. Not the prettiest code ever, but for proving the concept it seems to be adequate.

Comment: Can you show a fragment of your ontology including TomatoTopping, and how you set the short form provider for the parser? I suspect a namespace issue (i.e., TomatoTopping is not the same class you see in the hierarchy because it gets resolved to foo#TomatoTopping, but you are looking for bar#TomatoTopping)

Comment: I extracted the namespace and it is the same for everything. I can query TomatoTopping and check other facts. For example, this is valid: Class:TomatoTopping SubClassOf: VegetableTopping. However, my problem is how to query Nothing. I don't know if it is a logically plausible action or not.